# Salesforce Marketing Cloud REST vs SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, soap

This quetion is related to marketing cloud APIs. I need to perform below tasks on marketing cloud via API.

1. Create a Data Extension
2. Create a Query activity
3. Run query activity
4. Retrieve data from Data Extension.

Appreciate if you can suggest me to use SOAP or REST API for this. Ex : I found an example for creating a data extension using SOAP in API documentation, but couldn't fina an example from REST for the same. (I am executing API calls from Sales Clod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the majority of core system activities, SOAP is more fully fledged. REST is used for more recent functionality additions of the platform e.g. Journey Builder, Content Builder. For the use cases you list, then SOAP would be best.

An alternative to consider is to use the SDK - then you don't have to worry as to which one to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could do all the steps via SOAP API and it was success. Compared to other steps, it takes more time to complete the query execution. Do you have any idea to increase the query execution time? Thank you in advanced

Comment: @Gravitai I did not see an option in the Fuel SDK to get content builder emails. I had to set up my own REST calls using Guzzle. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go with SOAP, you can do all 4 with it.